# Can a Neo4j Graph Visualization on a VM be embedded in my flask UI?

Tags: python, html, flask, neo4j, azure-virtual-machine

I am currently running Neo4j on an Azure Virtual Machine and the graph visualization can be viewed in my web browser when the machine is running.

I have also created a UI in python with flask which is being run locally.

I want to be able to embed the graph visualization currently running on the Virtual Machine into my html code for the UI.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way to get my graph visualization into my UI?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to embed a web page of Neo4j graph visualization is to add HTML [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag with the page url of its `src` property into your flask view page, if there is no auth for the web page of Neo4j.

And I think the correct solution is to follow the Neo4j offical document [`Graph Visualization Tools`](https://neo4j.com/developer/tools-graph-visualization/) to embed a graph visualization in your flask application.

Comment: Is it possible to to obtain use the iframe if there is authentication?

Comment: @Rose If you can embed a page via the url for the property `src` of `iframe` tag with the query string of authentication, I think yes, otherwise no. And I recommended to follow the Neo4j offical document to do it, it's the best way and secure.